# Azure-logicApps-INSERTING ENTITY INTO A TABLE

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-api-management, azure-api-apps

i have created a HTTP post request using logic apps and inserting that in a table. so i need the row key to be 1,2, and 3 so on. when i insert first entity it Should be 1 and for next entity it should 2 so on. i have tried Guid no solution. please if someone knows share the answer.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to avoid guids, you have to use other ways to implement auto-increment, you could create a queue or a table entity with your next ids to use.

In the logic app before do insert action, read the queue or entity, increment and save it then insert with the value you read.

The below is my test logic app, use a itemid table to store the auto-increment id and insert the id as rowkey to destination table `test`. Then replace the entity in the `itemid` table with the new id value.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Replace_Entity' inputs at line '1' and column '1669': 'The template language function 'add' expects its first parameter to be an integer or a decimal number. The provided value is of type 'String'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#add for usage details.'.                      iam getting this errror

Comment: @user12395612, suppose your id type is string, in my test I set it with int32, if you want it be string bin your logic app you could use `int` expression to convert it to int. And the expression should be `add(int(outputs('Get_entity')['body']['id']),1)`

Comment: And looks like you could understand this flow, if this could help you, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: ya it is working. thank u so much. and in insert entity the row key should be this body('Get_entity')['id']. other than that everything correct. if there is any other way to implement this could be help full without having another table. if there is any let me know please.. once again thank u so much.

Comment: @user12395612, for now azure table doesn't support auto-increment property, so have to implement it by self, you could also use queue to do it.

Comment: If this could help you, please accept it as the answer.